# Why @Order is not working with beans in multiple config files using Spring 4.3.5.RELEASE JavaConfig?

Tags: spring

I have my 2 config files as below:

Config1 :

```
@Configuration
public class Config1 {

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public String example() {
      return new String("example1");
  }

}
```

Config 2:

```
@Configuration
public class Config2 {

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public String example() {
      return new String("example2");
  }

}
```

And my test class, which is a config as:

```
@Configuration
@Import({Config1.class, Config2.class})
public class TestApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestApp.class);
    System.out.println("Bean By Name:: " + ctx.getBean("example", String.class));

  }

}
```

After running the above code I am getting:

> Bean By Name:: example2

Instead of getting (since Config 1 has the lower number in @Order annotaion):

> Bean By Name:: example1

But, when I put all the beans in Config1 and maintain the @Order numbering I am getting expected results:

> Bean By Name:: example1

What's the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Because there is only 1 bean... 1 overrides the other and in that case the last one always wins. Ordering will only work if there are multiple beans of the same type you only have 1. You cannot merge them as you cannot have 2 methods with the same name.

Comment: Well, I got what you are saying and it makes sense. Thank you.